# Add To Array Value

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

this must be very simple but I couldn't make it work.. PHP noob :P

I have this array "$e_cats" and when I do var_dump($e_cats); the result is this:

```
array(3) { [0]=> string(3) "192" [1]=> string(3) "190" [2]=> string(3) "191" }
```

What I want is to add "-" to every value inside, so "-192", "-190", and "-191". Here is my code:

```
foreach ($e_cats as $cat) {
    $cat = '-' .$cat;
}
```

but when I do print_r($cat) the result is: -191 (not all values). What did I do wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: use `foreach ($e_cats as &$cat)` instead of `foreach ($e_cats as $cat)`.

Comment: HamZa, thanks mate, but it doesn't work. foreach ($e_cats as &$cat) {
 $cat = '-' .$cat;
}
print_r($cat);

result = -191

Comment: Look over the [part near the top of the `foreach` docs](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) about modifying array elements by reference.

Comment: @Mario88 See it [working](http://codepad.org/ssEwQo4y), or am I missing something ?

Comment: Unless you really need these as strings, PHP will cast them to ints so you can just do `$cat = -$cat;` !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach($e_cats as $i => $cat) {
    $e_cats[$i] = '-' . $cat;
}
```

You were close!